# problems with carrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, interop, pytables

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import tables as tb

ndim = 50000
h5in = tb.openFile('data.h5','r')
data = h5in.root.x

h5out = tb.openFile('testout.h5', mode='w', title="argsort distances")
root = h5out.root
x = h5out.createCArray(root,'x',tb.Int16Atom(),shape=(ndim,ndim))

for i in xrange(ndim):
    x[:,i] = np.argsort(dist[i,:])
```

It just takes an eternity executing. Does it exist any way to speed this up?

Note: It must be x[:,i] and not x[i,:]

Answer (score 1):

Replace the for loop with:

```
x[:,:] = np.argsort(dist, axis=1).T
```

**UPDATE**: If this is too large, then try to find a compromise in the slices size:

```
slice_size = 100 # or 1000 if it fits into your memory
for i in xrange(0, ndim, slice_size):
    x[:,i:i+slice_size] = np.argsort(dist[i:i+slice_size,:], axis=1)
```

Comment: @user1038382 - maybe you could try to work in slices… see my updated answer

Comment: if you use `slice_size` then `np.argsort()`'s return values should be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load a file which has data in the form of rows?

if yes, try np.loadtxt